# how to customizing swift firabase didselectedrowat

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

hello i am begginer to swift i get an error "Cannot assign value of type 'Character' to type '[String]'" how can i fix that my brain is now lost in this code blog `enter code here`

import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class PhoneViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var phoneModelText = [String]()
var imeiAdressText = [String]()
var userNameText = [String]()
var idText = [String]()
var phoneNumberText = [String]()
var detailsText = [String]()
var dateText = [String]()
var priceText = [String]()
var adressText = [String]()


var selectedPhoneModelText = ""
var selectedimeiAdressText = ""
var selecteduserNameText = ""
var selectedidText = ""
var selectedphoneNumberText = ""
var selecteddetailsText = ""
var selecteddateText = ""
var selectedpriceText = ""
var selectedadressText = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    getdata()
    
    
}

func makeAlert(titleInput: String, messageInput : String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleInput, message: messageInput, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okButton)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



func fetchBook(documentId: String) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
  let docRef = db.collection("Databases").document(documentId)
  docRef.getDocument { document, error in
    if let error = error as NSError? {
        self.makeAlert(titleInput: "alert", messageInput: "\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    else {
      if let document = document {
        let id = document.documentID
        let data = document.data()
        let phonemodel = data?["phoneName"] as? String ?? ""
        let imeiadress = data?["imeiNumberText"] as? Int ?? 0
        let username = data?["userNameText"] as? String ?? ""
        let idcard = data?["idCardtext"] as? Int ?? 0
        let phonenumber = data?["phoneNumberText"] as? Int ?? 0
        let adress = data?["adressNameText"] as? String ?? ""
        let details = data?["detailSectionText"] as? String ?? ""
        let date = data?["currentDateText"] as? String ?? ""
        let price = data?["priceValueText"] as? Int ?? 0
        let image = data?["imageurl"] as? String ?? ""
          
          

          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.selectedphoneNumberText = phonemodel
              
              
              
             self.phoneModelText.text = phonemodel
              self.imeiAdressText.text = String(imeiadress)
              self.userNameText.text = username
              self.idText.text = String(idcard)
              self.phoneNumberText.text = String(phonenumber)
              self.adressText.text = adress
              self.detailsText.text = details
              self.dateText.text = date
              self.priceText.text = String(price)

          }

      }
    }

  }
}
```

}

extension PhoneViewController : UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return phoneModelText.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = phoneModelText[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // how i customizing there
    

  
           performSegue(withIdentifier: "toPhoneListView", sender: nil)
    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toPhoneListView" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! PhoneListViewController
        destinationVC.selectedPhoneModelText
        destinationVC.selectedimeiAdressText
        destinationVC.selecteduserNameText
        destinationVC.selectedidText
        destinationVC.selectedphoneNumberText
        destinationVC.selecteddetailsText
        destinationVC.selecteddateText
        destinationVC.selectedpriceText
        destinationVC.selectedadressText
       }
   }
```

}

Comment: Why not make a struct that holds all your attributes? As for the error, you read `phonemodel` as a String then you try to assign it to `phoneModelText.text` where `phoneModelText` is declared as an array of String which means it doesn't have a property `text`. And why declare it as an array if it will only hold one item?

Comment: can you make it for me understandable because my brain working if when i see i learn about or if you give me simirlar example enought for me Thank you

Comment: With what exactly, your question is about the table view but if you load only one item from firebase then you don't need a table, right? And for creating a struct, this is pretty basic stuff, `struct Book { var phoneModelText: [String] var imeiAdressText = [String] ...//same for rest of the properties }`, of course you need to decide if it is `[String]` or just `String` for the types.

Comment: Welcome to SO. A couple of things about posting questions. 1) Code formatting is super important - prettier code gets better answers. 2) When you get an error, it's important to indicate what line is causing the error so we can focus on the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your phoneModelText is defined

```
var phoneModelText = [String]()
```

that indicates that phoneModelText is an array of strings, so it would look something like this

```
phoneModelText[0] = "Some String"
phoneModelText[1] = "Another string"
```

but then later you're attempting to assign string to that array

```
self.phoneModelText.text = phonemodel
```

And that's not how arrays work. If you want to add `phoneModel` to the array it would be this

```
self.phoneModelText.append(phoneModel) //assume phoneModel = "yet another string"
```

so then the array would look like this

```
phoneModelText[0] = "Some String"
phoneModelText[1] = "Another string"
phoneModelText[2] = "yet another string"
```

In general I would suggest naming your vars so they more represent what they contain - instead of phoneModelText, call it phoneModelTextArray. That wil reduce confusion and make the code more readable.

As far as a solution, it's not clear why there are a bunch of arrays

```
var phoneModelText = [String]()
var imeiAdressText = [String]()
var userNameText = [String]()
```

but I suggest changing all of that around. One option is to define  a class with properties and then have an array of classes

```
class ContactClass {
   var id = ""
   var phoneText = ""
   var imeiAdressText = ""
   var userNameText = ""
}
```

and then an array of classes within your controller

```
var contactArray = [ContactClass]()
```

and then lastly, when reading data from Firebase, instantiate the class, populate the class properties and add the class to the array

```
else {
  if let document = document {
    let contact = ContactClass()
    
    contact.id = document.documentID
    contact.phoneText = data?["phoneName"] as? String ?? ""
    contact.imeiAdressText = data?["imeiNumberText"] as? Int ?? 0
    contact.userNameText = data?["userName"] as? String ?? ""
    
    self.contactArray.append(contact)
```

Comment: i have a question 1 more i fetch data to firebase but how i pass other vc can you help me all fetching data to send other vc evrey cell when i clicked i need what i am write didselectrowat functions

Comment: @newcoder That sounds like it would be best suited for a separate question! It's going t be hard to answer that in comments (code doesn't do well in comments, lol). There are a LOT of other questions here on SO about how to pass data to another viewController - and there are a number of ways to do it as well. So do a bit of research first and then post a question with some code and we will take a look!